# TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python

Estou tentando fazer uma intersecção entre dois arrays usando a lib `re`, porém está me retornando a seguinte saída:

**OUTPUT:**

> selectobj = filter(regex.search, result_psql) TypeError: expected
>   string or buffer

**Explicando script:**

`diff_array` = São os elementos que devem ser comparados, é um array gerado dentro do script, com a função abaixo:

```
diff_array = []
def diff(first, second):
    second = set(second)
    return [item for item in first if item not in second]
```

`result_psql` = elementos são um select no banco de dados PSQL

```
result_psql = cursorpost.fetchall()
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
for element in diff_array:
    regex = re.compile(r'.*'+element+'')
    selectobj = filter(regex.search, result_psql)
    print(selectobj)
```

**OBJETIVO:**

Quero fazer uma intersecção entre dois arrays, onde deve ser retornado os elementos que são parecidos, assim como é feito com o **LIKE** do **SQL**

Comment: Luis, você não especifica qual biblioteca está usando para conectar com o banco de dados, mas vou supor que esta biblioteca siga a [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) que normaliza as APIs de banco de dados. Você verá que o método [`Cursor.fetchall()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchall) retorna uma sequência de sequências. Sabendo disso, você verá que o método [`RegExp.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) recebe uma string como primeiro argumento.. Então é provável que seu erro seja este.

Comment: E também, seu método `diff` poderia usar conjuntos se a ordem não importar.. O método todo poderia ser substituído por `set(first) & set(second)`... Ficaria mais performático.

Comment: @fernandosavio estou utilizando os seguintes imports: requests, json, sys, psycopg2, re, datetime e re

Comment: Eu devo passar ao RegExp.search() como string ?